# the code to change the background color to this that write in the textbox

Tags: javascript

I wrote code that need to changes the background color to the color that write in the textbox and this no work.

I will happy to help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BqnA.png)

Comment: Show us what you have tried!

Comment: Your image of code doesn't include a complete [mcve] either.

Comment: Please use stackoverflow with responsibility. Learn and help others learn. Don't just post any problem without any research.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is wrong 
actually you are trying to change the color only if the color in text box its the same as the body css color.
in this case has no effect.

make it

```
if(a !== ...){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please provide the fill file and the error so we can help you out not with pictures.